# Modulus of a complex expression

Tags: complex-numbers

$ \alpha , \beta \in \mathbb{C}$. Find |$\alpha - (\alpha^{2}-\beta^{2})^\frac 12$| + |$\alpha + (\alpha^{2}-\beta^{2})^\frac 12$| . I am having trouble in understanding how they ended at the second step in the solution given below, I mean doesn't it depends on the argument between terms or it just happens every time? [image]

Comment: Just to make sure: is your question about how they found $2(|\alpha|^2+\dots^2)+2|\alpha^2-(\alpha^2-\beta^2)|$ from the previous line? $$|\alpha-z|^2+|\alpha+z|^2=|\alpha|^2+|z|^2-2\Re(\bar\alpha z)+|\alpha|^2+|z|^2+2\Re(\bar\alpha z)$$

Comment: Yes exactly.  Thank you so much. Actually, I never knew we could do such expansion